# is 5 weeks enough for my double IPA?

Tags: fermentation, bottling, first-time-brewer, dry-hop, ipa

I am Currently working on a double IPA with a predicted abv between 8%-9%..I am leaving it in one vessel. I was wondering if anyone thought 4 weeks in primary, then adding my dryhops and leaving for one more week before bottling, for a total of 5 weeks, would be enough time for the beer to be fully fermented and ready to package. Also going to leave bottled for 3 weeks before first taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You'll likely be fully fermented within 1 week, if you have a healthy pitch of yeast. Two weeks should be more than enough. Gravity readings are your best option to understanding fermentation/attenuation, here.

Comment: but it will not hurt it to leave in for 5 weeks before bottling right? I just want it to sit there for a good bit of time and really marry the flavors. I just don't want to ruin anything, i've been doing everything perfectly. Sadly, when i purchased the hydrometer i didn't realize i needed a tube for the beer (i thought it came with) and so i didn't have a big enough vessel to take the reading. This really bummed me out but like I said I've done everything to a T.

Comment: It will not hurt to leave it for 5 weeks. I would recommend delaying the dry-hop addition until just one week before bottling, as you had planned, to retain as much hop character as possible.

Comment: I plan on dry hopping one week before bottling for sure! If i want to cold crash, do i dry hop before or after?

Comment: Dry hop then cold crash. Cold crashing encourages both the yeast and the dry hop particles to settle out, leaving behind a clearer beer.

Comment: I agree with @bughunter, but would recommend allowing at least a day or two after dry hopping for the yeast to consume the oxygen that came in with the dry hops. Then cold crash when you are ready.

Comment: At least a day or two. You should dry hop near fermentation temps, not cold-crash temps.